# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Quadrotor control using ArduIMU](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/quadrotor-control-using-arduimu)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Using an Xbox controller to fly a Quadrocopter](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/using-an-xbox-controller-to-fly-a-quadrocopter)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What are the signs that a servo might be broken?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/what-are-the-signs-that-a-servo-might-be-broken)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Drone targeting](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/drone-targeting)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to detect when a stepper motor has stalled?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/how-to-detect-when-a-stepper-motor-has-stalled)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How can a load be balanced between multiple AC electric drive motors?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/how-can-a-load-be-balanced-between-multiple-ac-electric-drive-motors)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How do I adjust objects on a conveyor belt into the proper orientation?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/how-do-i-adjust-objects-on-a-conveyor-belt-into-the-proper-orientation)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to measure and dispense a finite amount of powder or liquid](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/how-to-measure-and-dispense-a-finite-amount-of-powder-or-liquid)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What kind of sensor do i need for knowing that something is placed at a position?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/what-kind-of-sensor-do-i-need-for-knowing-that-something-is-placed-at-a-position)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the difference between Task-Level and Joint-Level Control Systems?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1253/what-is-the-difference-between-task-level-and-joint-level-control-systems)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting that for each of the questions I reviewed, doing a web search on the topics involved gave the *robotics* page in the top ten hits for those search terms. There were some forums posts which went into more detail than our answers here, but some of these longer answers were answering slightly different questions.

Generally the answers were of a satisfactory standard, but there were a number which needed improvement and few outstanding ones, with [Ian](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/350/ian)'s answers really standing out. *8')

Since the search terms I used were drawn from the question there will be some [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) in my opinion, but I think this still bodes well for out site overall.