# Do we want to arrange chat events?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Asimov's Corner](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221) (our chat room) can be a lonely place, so since we have the facility to [create events](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6221/asimovs-corner?tab=schedule), why not lets make use of it?

Other sites have (semi) regular chat events, times when people can get together and chat about particular topics of interest. For instance [Electrical Engineering](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/15/electrical-engineering?tab=schedule) have a weekly *EE.SE hangout* event which happens at 15:00 (in my time zone<sup>†</sup>) on Saturday and lasts 60 minutes and [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) has had at least one [Group Watching event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1128). These sound like a great idea to me.

<sup>† 15:00 BST London is: 07:00 PDT San Francisco ; 10:00 EDT New York ; 14:00 UTC ; 20:00 IST New Delhi ; 00:00 AEST Canberra</sup>

Here on *robotics* we appear to have plenty of people with beginner or non constructive questions which would be better off asked in a chat environment than as questions on the site. We also have lots of people who are interested in quadcopters, so I would suggest that we might want to run either a *getting started* or a *quadcopter* session as our first chat event. This would be a great place to share experience, explore design options or ask for product recommendations, all things which make for poor questions on our main site.

If people think this is a good idea, then which day of the week and time of day would be a good time to hold the event? The *EE hangout* time seems like a reasonable compromise, since it keeps almost everyone on the same day and means that people who would otherwise be working or studying can participate.

Other possible events could coincide with events in the real world, to both get them onto our events calendar, remind people that they are happening and giving people a chat room to talk about them as they are happening. I'm thinking of Conferences, trade shows, or any other events of note to roboticists.

We could also meet up to discuss the current [site self-evaluation](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/37) and I would be happy to have an event to provide Feedback for moderators, so that we can discuss what people feel we are getting right and bringing to light anything people feel is less than ideal.

So, what do people think about arranging some chat events? What do we want to discuss and when do we want to discuss it?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a fantastic idea. I agree that a beginner's or quadcopter event is a good first event. We can even start a thread on meta so people can vote whichever one they prefer.